# How to style an Anchor tag in react application

Tags: reactjs, css-in-js

I am working on a react application and trying to style an Anchor like below.
I have not been able to do this. The color red is not applied. How can I style this?

**JS**

```js
function styles({ palette }: Theme) {
  return {
    anchorStyle: {
      color: "red",
    },
  };
}
```

**JSX**

```html
<Anchor onClick={() => checkView()} className={classes.anchorStyle}>
  {!myUser ? "First view" : "Second view"}
</Anchor>;
```

Comment: Is `classes` in the second snippet somehow related to the `styles` function from the first snippet? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example and more details about what is or isn't working as expected, error messages, etc...

Comment: The red color I am trying to apply does not show the font as red.